# Making an integral arbitrarily small as the radius becomes arbitrarily large

Tags: complex-analysis

I have encountered some questions in complex analysis where a technique of making an integral arbitrarily small by making the radius arbitrarily large is used. The technique is used in this question for example:

> Let $f$ be holomorphic in $\mathbb{C}$ such that $f(z) \rightarrow 0$ as $\lvert z\rvert \rightarrow \infty$. Prove that $f$ is identically zero.

where we have the inequality

$|f'(z)| \leq \frac{1}{2\pi i}\oint_{C_R}\left|\frac{f(w)dw}{(w-z)^2}\right|$

but I don't understand why the integral becomes arbitrarily small as the radius becomes arbitrarily large. Please help.

Comment: You could use the maximum principle. Or Liouville's theorem.

Answer (score 1):

The definition of a limit can be used to show that $|f(z)|$ is bounded. You can say that for every $\epsilon>0$ there exists a radius $R$ such that $|f(z)|<\epsilon$ outside a disk of radius $R$ with the origin as center. So, for some particular choice of $\epsilon$ you have that $|f(z)|$ is bounded in the exterior of the disk, while inside a the disk it's also bounded due to $f(z)$ being analytic.

Then you can set up the argument in Liouville's theorem which shows that a bounded analytic function must be a constant. Here you use the fact that the derivative of $f(z)$ at some point can be expressed as a contour integral:

$$f'(z) = \frac{1}{2\pi i}\oint_{C_R}\frac{f(w)dw}{(w-z)^2}$$

where $C_R$ is a counterclockwise circle of radius $R$ with $z$ as its center. Taking absolute values yields:

$$|f'(z)| \leq \frac{1}{2\pi}\oint_{C_R}\left|\frac{f(w)dw}{(w-z)^2}\right|$$

Then since $|f(w)|$ is smaller than some number $M$ we see that the right hand side can be made arbitrarily small by taking the radius arbitrarily large. To see this, we can evaluate the r.h.s. of the inequality by putting $w = z + R\exp(i\theta)$ and integrate over $\theta$. Using that $|f(w)|\leq M$ we find the bound:

$$\frac{1}{2\pi}\int_0^{2\pi}\frac{M}{R^2}\left|d\left(R\exp(i\theta)\right)\right| =\frac{1}{2\pi}\int_0^{2\pi}\frac{M}{R^2}\left|d\left(R\exp(i\theta)\right)\right|=\frac{M}{R}$$

The conclusion is that $f'(z)$ is equal to zero everywhere, therefore $f(z)$ is a constant. The fact that $f(z)$ tends to zero at infinity then implies that this constant is zero.

Comment: What you wrote is correct only if $|f(z)|\to 0$ uniformly as $|z| \to \infty$. (Alice Roth I think) showed there are some non-constant (nor bounded) entire functions whose radial limit is $0$, i.e. for every $\theta$ : $\lim_{r \to +\infty} f(r e^{i \theta}) = 0$

Comment: ...although usually when people talk about convergence at infinity, it is implicit that they mean uniform convergence.

Comment: I've seen similar arguments before. The part I don't understand is that 'the right hand side can be made arbitrarily small by taking the radius arbitrarily large'.

Comment: @Urthona26 I've added a bit more explanations

Comment: @user1952009 That's interesting, I'll modify the answer.

Comment: Thank you. Why does $\lvert d(R\exp(i\theta))\rvert$ appear rather than $\lvert d(z+R\exp(i\theta)\rvert$, given that the substitution was $w=z+R\exp(i\theta)$?

Comment: @Urthona26 z is constant in the integral, it is the center of the circle we're integrating over, the integration variable is the angular variable $\theta$.